# Build Test Class For Invocable Apex Class (Invalid type: FilterObjectsByIds.filter)

Tags: apex, unit-test, error, debug, help

I'm having difficulties building a test class for an Apex Class I found online, being used in a Flow to help update records from a many-to-many relationship.

With the current setup, I get the error message for line 38

> (Invalid type: FilterObjectsByIds.filter)

**Class**

```apex
global class FilterObjectsByIDs {
    @InvocableMethod
    global static List <Results> filter(List<Requests> requestList) {
        List<Results> responseWrapper = new List<Results>();
        for (Requests curRequest : requestList) {
            Results response = new Results();
            List<ID> containingCollection = curRequest.containingCollection;
            //List<ID> containingCollection;

            String objectName = curRequest.objectName;
            String returnFields = curRequest.returnFields;
            String bindField = curRequest.bindField;
            if (returnFields == '' || returnFields == null)
                returnFields = 'Id';
            if (bindField == '' || bindField == null)
                bindField = 'Id';
            
            if (containingCollection != null && !containingCollection.isEmpty() && objectName != null) {
                String queryString;
                queryString = 'SELECT ' + returnFields + ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE ' + bindField + ' IN :containingCollection'; 
                System.debug ('queryString is: ' + queryString);
               // queryString = 'SELECT Name,Id,CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId IN :containingCollection';
                response.foundRecords = Database.query(queryString);
            } else {
                throw new InvocableActionException('ContainingCollection or ObjectName did not contain valid values');
            }
            
            responseWrapper.add(response);
        }

        return responseWrapper;
    }
    
    global class InvocableActionException extends Exception {}

    global class Requests {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        global String objectName;

        @InvocableVariable
        global String returnFields;

        @InvocableVariable
        global String bindField;

        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        global List<ID> containingCollection;
    }

    global class Results {
        @InvocableVariable
        global String errors;

        @InvocableVariable
        global List<SObject> foundRecords;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```apex
/**
 * @author ()
 * @version 1.0
 * @description tbd
 *
 * 2022-07-20 : - 
 **/
@isTest
public class FilterObjectByIDsTest {
    //Create 2 fake Contacts to use in testing
    @testSetup
    static void dataCreation(){
        Contact contact1 = new Contact(LeadSource = 'Sales Self-Generated', Email = 'contact1@gmail.com', FirstName = 'Contact', LastName = '1', Type__c = 'Finance');
        Contact contact2 = new Contact(LeadSource = 'Sales Self-Generated', Email = 'contact2@gmail.com', FirstName = 'Contact', LastName = '2', Type__c = 'Finance');
        insert new List<Contact>{contact1, contact2};
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void testGetContactRecords(){
        List<FilterObjectsByIDs.Requests> requestList = new List<FilterObjectsByIDs.Requests>();
        FilterObjectsByIDs.Requests req = new FilterObjectsByIDs.Requests();
        
        //Collect list of IDs from Contacts and add into contactIDs List
        List<Id> contactIDs = new List<Id>();
        for(Contact c : [SELECT ID FROM Contact]){
            contactIDs.add(c.Id);
        }
        
        //Build up the string for FilterObjectByIDs class
        req.objectName = 'Contact';
        req.containingCollection = contactIDs;
        req.returnFields = 'Id, FirstName';
        requestList.add(req);
        
        //Start the test
        Test.startTest();
        List<FilterObjectsByIDs.Requests> responseList = new FilterObjectsByIDs.filter(requestList);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Tried my test class, I expected it to work properly but I'm getting an invalid type error

Comment: `FilterObjectsByIDs.filter` is a static method, therefore you don't need to create a new instance of the class. Drop the `new` keyword, i.e. just use `FilterObjectsByIDs.filter(requestList);` instead

Comment: @PhilHawthorn That should really be an `Answer`.

Comment: Some feedback: you should try to build an aggregate of all queries coming in so you can do as few as you need to. This will require significant amounts of work, but would allow you to avoid the too many SOQL error when running this in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

`FilterObjectsByIDs.filter` is a [static](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm) method, therefore you don't need to create a new instance of the class. Drop the `new` keyword, i.e.

`List<FilterObjectsByIDs.Requests> responseList = new FilterObjectsByIDs.filter(requestList);`

Simply becomes:

`List<FilterObjectsByIDs.Requests> responseList = FilterObjectsByIDs.filter(requestList);`